# Apache mod_rewrite from unfriendly query string to a friendly URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to regex and Apache mod_rewrite, I have tried several ways, it doesn’t convert to URL friendly, I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

I want to convert from unfriendly query string to a friendly URL on these scenarios:

Scenario 1:
From: https://example.com/page.php?page_url=life-is-good
To: https://example.com/life-is-good/

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$  /page.php?page_url=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Scenario 2:
From: https://example.com/resources/?blog.php?blog_url=life-is-good
To: https://example.com/blogs/life-is-good/

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(blogs)/(.*)/$ blogs/blog.php?blog_url=$2 [L,R=301]
```

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you should already be linking to the "friendly URL" internally. Any redirect you implement in `.htaccess` to "convert" the URL (as in the answer below) is really only for the benefit of SEO and users following 3rd party links to the "old" (unfriendly) URLs.

Comment: `/resources/?blog.php?blog_url=life-is-good` - presumably that first `?` is a typo?

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this, there will be old external links using unfriendly query string, I want all of those to be redirected to the friendly URLs too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(blogs)/blog\.php\?blog_url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?page_url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]

# ignore all the requests for existing files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal forwards from pretty URL to actual one

RewriteRule ^(blogs)/(.*)/$ $1/blog.php?blog_url=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?page_url=$1 [L,QSA]
```